# Axios POST request missing payload

Tags: vue.js, axios, httprequest, nuxtjs

I have several post requests with axios in my Nuxtjs app.
They all work fine except for one and I can't figure out why:

This is the POST request:

```js
await this.$axios.post('question_logic/', {
          ifLogic: q.logic.ifLogic,
          thenLogic: q.logic.thenLogic,
          question: q.id,
        })
```

Which trigger a 400 error:

```
REQUEST HEADERS:
---------------------------------------
POST /api/question_logic/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Token ******************************* (<-- obscured)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en

RESPONSE HEADERS:
---------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 11:31:45 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.6
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 40
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```

What puzzle me is that inspecting the network on chrome devTools I see that the `request payload` is incomplete:
[image]

In particular is missing the `question` attribute that is clearly in the request. From my limited debugging experience, I think that this is the cause of the 400 error but I have no clue on how to resolve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If `question` has `undefined` value it will not be serialized

Comment: Can you share more details about your code? Specifically about what is 'q' object and how its data is setting. Also check the q object right before you use it as axios post payload to see if it has all the right values that you want in it or not

Comment: You can try with `question: q.id || 0`

Comment: Sorry guys I was Anatoly was correct, there was an issue on my code that sent an undefined question. I made the mistake of having recursive async functions in my code so I made a major change and merge all async requests in a single one so to be able to better manage the request.